# Speed of hinted handoff in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Given a particular set of configurations and a particular size of data to be written on a node, can we predict how much time will the hinted handoff take to finish? 
In my case, as soon as the node came up, I checked using the 'nodetool statushandoff' command, that the hinted handoff had started running. However, it seems to be running endlessly. So is there any way by looking at the configurations, missing data size etc. so that we can know that after this much amount of time, the missing data will be written on the node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to track the progress with some hint metrics. Have a look on this page: http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/metrics.html#hintedhandoff-metrics

The TotalHintsInProgress will tell you how big the backlog is and TotalHints will tell you the number of hints written on the node since startup. So by tracking these two metrics you should be able to give an estimate (good or bad) on how far it's come.